# How do I get Sentry reference ID in html template using sentry-sdk?

Tags: python, django, sentry, raven

Since the `raven` is deprecated I need an alternative way to display Sentry reference ID in my html template.

The previous version looks like this from the [example](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/#message-references):

```
<p>You've encountered an error, oh noes!</p>
{% if request.sentry.id %}
<p>
  If you need assistance, you may reference this error as
  <strong>{{ request.sentry.id }}</strong>.
</p>
{% endif %}
```

How do I do this now? I tried to use `sentry_sdk.capture_exception()` or `sentry_sdk.last_event_id()` method. The first one returns None in my template, the second one looks like it's now what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Sentry has a new User Feedback function.

Here are the docs: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/django/enriching-events/user-feedback/

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, and likely are to be deleted. You should add the relevant information into your answer